# Migrate SQL Server Express to existing Oracle database with migrations

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-6, database-migration

I have a project with a SQL Server Express database and Entity Framework migrations. But I need to migrate my SQL Server Express database to Oracle. But Oracle database has existing tables. How can I migrate to Oracle?

If I set Oracle connection strings and run a command `update-database` in package manager console, will existing database tables be deleted? Or what is the best way?

Answer (score -1):

Funny question does the Oracle db tables have data stored?